# Simple animation using keyframes not working

Tags: css, animation

Simple animation using keyframes not working, not sure what I've done wrong. When I run it all I see is a still car image. New to this stuff so apologies if this question makes you want to facepalm.

css

```css
@charset "utf-8";

@-webkit-keyframes drive {
 from {-webkit-transform: translateX(0px);}
 to {-webkit-transform: translateX(800px);}
}

body {
 background:#FFF;
}

.wrapper {
 margin: 1em auto;
 width: 960px;
 position:relative;
}

.drive {
 position: relative;
 top:10px;
 left:10px;
 webkit-animation-name: drive;
 webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
 webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
 webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

html
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>CSS Using Keyframes</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my-css-1.css">
</head>

<body>
<!--<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>-->

Animation Keyframe Basics

<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="car.png" alt="car" class="drive"/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
webkit-animation-name: drive;
webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
```

with:

```
-webkit-animation-name: drive;
-webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
```

Also note that this will work in webkit browsers. You'll need browser specific css achieve cross browser support.